# ¿Cómo podía agregar a una calculadora simple que al tomar una decisión esta repita o deje de repetir el resultado?

Tags: javascript, html, array, condiciones, switch

Muy buen día, disculpen por la pregunta es que tenia una duda acerca de como repetir la operación una y otra vez hasta que el usuario diga que ya no, es decir, Al  inicio solicita la operación a realizar y al término deberá preguntar al usuario ¿Desea volver a ejecutar otra operación S/N?, donde el usuario deberá ingresa S o N.

aquí esta el código, les agradecería mucho la ayuda en verdad por favor y disculpen las molestias

```
    varA=parseFloat(prompt("introducas un numero"));
    varB=parseFloat(prompt("introducas un numero otro numero"));
    varC=parseFloat(prompt("introducas un ultimo numero"));
    signo=prompt("ponga un signo");


    if(signo == '+') {
    resultado=(varA+varB+varC);
    }else if(signo == '-'){
    resultado=(varA-varB-varC);
    }else if(signo == '*'){
    resultado=(varA*varB*varC);
    }else if(signo == '/'){
    resultado=(varA/varB/varC);
    }
    document.write(resultado);
```

Comment: A buenas y primeras te diría que con un bucle while, pero falta contexto. Hace el favor de poner el resto del código

Comment: @Sancaf muchas gracias por comentar y disculpa, ya agregue lo que faltaba del código y muchas gracias en verdad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías envolver todo en una declaración `while`. Lo que haya dentro se va a ejecutar mientras la condición dada sea verdadera. Para eso declaramos una variable `otra` en true, para que acceda a la primer operación siempre (también podrías usar `do while` para esto).
Entramos al `while` y lo primero que hacemos es todo tu codigo, donde se ingresan las variables y se realiza la operacion.

Finalmente, le pedis otro valor de entrada al usuario, el cual debe ser `true` o `false` para saber si quiere continuar o no. Si responde `true` se vuelve a ejecutar el bucle `while`, en el momento que responda `false` el bucle no se vuelve a ejecutar.

```
let otra = true;

while(otra){
    varA=parseFloat(prompt("introducas un numero"));
    varB=parseFloat(prompt("introducas un numero otro numero"));
    varC=parseFloat(prompt("introducas un ultimo numero"));
    signo=prompt("ponga un signo");


    if(signo == '+') {
    resultado=(varA+varB+varC);
    }else if(signo == '-'){
    resultado=(varA-varB-varC);
    }else if(signo == '*'){
    resultado=(varA*varB*varC);
    }else if(signo == '/'){
    resultado=(varA/varB/varC);
    }
    document.write(resultado);
 
    // aca le pedis que ingrese (por teclado, apretando un boton, lo 
    // que sea) si desea ejecutar otra operacion, y asignas este valor 
    // (true o false) a la variable "otra".

    // otra = true  <- se vuelve a ejecutar el bucle
    // otra = false <- se detiene el bucle
}
```

**Es necesario modificar la variable `otra` en el bucle `while`, SIEMPRE, para que de alguna forma pueda tomar como resultado `false`, de lo contrario siempre sería `true` y entraría un bucle infinito**

Comment: en verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda :,)